# aplay options -R or -s parameter

Tags: boot, alsa, audio

How can I set aplay to delay playing an audio file for 10 or 15 seconds.
I have aplay set to play at boot time - it plays my audio file about 10 seconds before the login screen and then when I login it continues for about 7 seconds (which is no problem) but I want to delay it playing until the login screen appears.  Right now its about 15 seconds early.  aplay -R or -s parameter.  How would that look since its microseconds for the -R and tick mins for the -s (sleep)

What would be the best option for delay.  Thank you

Solved

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          defaultdaemon
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $all
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INF
sleep 5;
echo "Playing startup sound"
aplay /boot/Orbital.wav 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

Comment: This plays right at the login screen

Answer (score 0):

`aplay` has no option to delay the playing.
(The -R and -s parameters do something different.)

Run [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep) before running `aplay`, or write a script that runs these two.

A better idea would be to run `aplay` not at boot time but at the login.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I used the sleep command and wrote a script to start at startup after everything else loads.  My audio now plays where I wanted it to start and that is right when I get to the login screen.